# Does canvas context2d.drawImage( webglCanvas, 0, 0 ) block until a webgl is finished rendering?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, webgl

I assume the answer is "no" from my testing but I thought I'd make sure.

I'm trying to draw / copy the contents from a WebGL canvas to a 2d canvas every frame and I want to know if I should wait until the WebGL context is finished drawing (which I can use gl.fenceSync to check) before calling it or if I can call `drawImage` immediately without worrying about a performance hit. Here's how I would plan to use it using three.js as a stand in renderer:

```js
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRendeer();
const canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

// ...

function renderLoop() {

    renderer.render( camera, scene1 );
    ctx.drawImage( renderer.domElement, 0, 0 );

    renderer.render( camera, scene2 );
    ctx.drawImage( renderer.domElement, 0, 0 );

}
```

Is there a pitfall here I'm missing?

Thank you!

---

Edit

Per gman's request here's an example demonstrating that the function seems to not block by performing a lot of GPU work (50000 instanced cubes with no depth write) before calling `drawImage`. The drawImage functions takes the same amount of time whether there is one cube or 50000 cubes and whether it's called before or after `render()` which leads me to believe `drawImage` does not block. Tested on a 2017 Mac laptop with latest Chrome:

https://jsfiddle.net/sL9npto6/

Comment: My request was you use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) not jsfiddle ;)  And it **does** block or rather it makes sure the results of all the previous WebGL calls are finished before copying to the canvas. If it didn't block then you'd be missing cubes.

Comment: Sorry a fiddle was easier for me :) I'm understanding that the browser will wait until the rendering has finished to copy and present but `drawImage` will return immediately, which is what I was concerned about. Is that right? EDIT: Continuing discussion in below comment.

Comment: FYI: fiddles are often off topic on S.O.  If we can't figure out the issue without having to go look offsite then your question would be off topic. It's not this case but you should get use to using snippets. You can just copy the fiddle into a snippet. For es6 modules put the js in the HTML section surrounded by `<script type="module></script>`. It will take less than 10 seconds.

Comment: Understood -- I'll keep that in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does canvas context2d.drawImage( webglCanvas, 0, 0 ) block until a webgl is finished rendering?

Yes, it effectively blocks

The last example on [this page](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-multiple-scenes.html) does exactly what your render loop shows.

If you have some example that you think shows otherwise make a minimal repo and post it a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Thanks I just added a fiddle. I guess "block" could mean two things here: 1. `drawImage` does not return until the webgl rendering finishes or 2. the the browser will wait until webgl rendering finishes and copy the image before presenting but `drawImage` returns immediately. I'm asking about the first which does not seem to happen. Seeing as you demonstrate it in your article (with a caveat about performance) do you recommend this technique?`drawImage` is taking ~0.1ms on my laptop which is acceptable. But are there scenarios where this could result in a huge performance hit? Thank you again!

Comment: I can't recommend something if I don't know what you're trying to do ;)

Comment: I'm considering building a time series line graphs for streaming data (new data every frame) for several (3 - 10+) charts on a page with multiple plots per chart at once using WebGL. I don't want to use a WebGL context per chart because of the limit and other rendering will be on the page, too. I plan to use a single background GL context and copy results to a 2d canvas context to display. If there are too many charts to render per frame I will update only one chart per frame until they are all updated or render a single plot w/ transparent bg per frame and composite until they are all done.

Comment: Well if you go back to the page linked in the answer, it would be faster to use 1 full screen canvas and just set the viewport and scissor because then there is no copy. So it's up to you. If the speed of copying is fast enough (you should check on many different browsers with different GPUs) then fine. If not, you can avoid the copy using viewport and scissor

Comment: I'm familiar with that technique but I was hoping to cut down on some complexity by copying by the canvas contents. But I just tested in Safari and Firefox and the performance there with drawImage is terrible -- almost 100ms in FF and 2-3ms in Safari. I didn't expect the performance discrepancy between browsers to be THAT high... I guess that's what I get for making any kind of assumptions about browsers. Back to the drawing board, I suppose. Anyway thank you again for your help and suggestions!